# Show Owner of Nuget Package in Visual Studio Packet Manager

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

Is it possible to make Visual Studio show the owner of a nuget package inside the nuget packet manager within Visual Studio?

The package manager for nuget packages in Visual Studio (up to current Visual Studio 2015) by default only shows the author of the package but not the owner.

From a security perspective, this is a very bad idea, because the owner is the actual person or institution that has the right to upload files to the package while the author is just some text information specified by the owner.

Look for example at [this nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom/). It contains a binary dll that is usually part of a MS SQL Server or Visual Studio installation. In the package manager inside Visual Studio we only see the "author" of the package as "Microsoft", but we don't see that the actual owner is an individual software developer not affiliated with Microsoft at all.

**Within Visual Studio:**
[image]
[image]

**On Nuget.org website:**
[image]
If that owner has a malicious intent (or his nuget account is hacked) he could upload a binary with an exploit that would then be downloaded and executed on numerous development machines and maybe even end user systems (if a setup is built from the package)

So question: Is there any way to make Visual Studio display the owner of a package so we can know whether the package comes from a trustworthy source?

It would already be good to be able to easily open the package information page on nuget.org for a certain package from within Visual Studio.

Comment: The UI would need to be modified. You should report this at [NuGet's issue tracker](https://www.nuget.org/home/issues).

Comment: Issue seems to [have been reported since April 2015](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/442), but not been implemented so far

Comment: The owners information shows on Nuget.org website means Nuget.org website has permission to show the owners personal information. But if Microsoft doesn't have this permission, Microsoft could not show the owners information directly. So if you want to know the owner for the packages, please check it from Nuget.org website.

Answer (score 2):

Current version of NuGet Package Manager is only show the Author of the packages. We could view the Owners from nuget.org site at present.

I submitted this feature request to Visual Studio User Voice. You could vote and add your comments for this feedback.

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/16946374-show-owner-of-nuget-package-in-visual-studio-packe